# Hide Data in asp.net GridView Except When Editing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit, show-hide, sensitive-data

I am using asp:GridView to display a data table in asp.net, .aspx page.
I have a column that contains sensitive information. 
I would like to display the column with the data grayed out or any other method to hide it so there isn't just a huge visible list of this data column, when the page/gridview loads.
However, when the edit button is clicked on a particular row I would like the sensitive data in the column to be visible and editable.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: So what is hiding purpose? When edit button is clicked, this sensitive data is shown, any reason of hiding?

Comment: I just don't want every row showing the data when the page / gridview loads.  It is alright for the user to look at a single row at a time since the same user entered the sensitive data. Additionally, it prevents printing off a complete list of this data and makes it harder for someone to look over their shoulder to see this data especially if it is only visible in one row while editing.

Comment: @Baxter what is the point of let people to edit the data that you don't want them to see??

Comment: @huMpty duMpty see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the column to a template.

Then you can edit the GridView templates.  There are different templates for viewing and editing.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't want to show the data why show that in edit mode ? People can also gaze in edit mode?
2. You can either open a modal dialog/popup window if you were to hide granular details of your data in gridview.
3. For now, you can either use **DataKeys** of gridview & define this column as gridview's dataKey
4. You can also, set a property on your page set to true or false when the edit button is clicked & switch control visibility like (this would work automatically during databind event)

   ```
   private bool isEdit; 
   protected bool IsEditMode
           {
             get {return isEdit;}
            set {isEdit=value;
           }
   ```

Then in your aspx you will switch desired controls visiblity simply by

> `Visible='<%# IsEditMode %>'`

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use the *rowdatabound* event of the gridview to do your job. Find the specific control, (probably textbox) in the current row and then simply set disabled = true. Or you can also set visible=false to hide that particular control from that row. If I;m getting you properly, then this should do your job.